# Plotting date or time as x axis with ggplot

Tags: python, plot, pandas, python-ggplot

My data is of the form:

```
datetime, count
2011-01-01 00:00:00, 10
2011-01-01 01:00:00, 15
2011-01-01 02:00:00, 20
...
```

Using ggplot, I want to plot following 2 graphs:

1. Change in count over time
2. Change in count over day

I was able to plot the first one by converting string to pandas datetime

```
csv_file['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_file['datetime'])
```

and then plotting it using ggplot.

For the second one, I converted datetime to time

```
csv_file['time'] = csv_file['datetime'].map(methodcaller('time'))

type(csv_file['time'][4]) = <type 'datetime.time'>
```

But while plotting, I'm getting this error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Plotting code:

```
ggplot1 =  ggplot(aes(x='time', y='count'), data=csv_file) + \
        geom_point(color='lightblue') + \
        stat_smooth(span=.15, color='black', se=True) + \
        ggtitle("Test") + \
        xlab("time") + \
        ylab("count")

    ggplot1.draw()
```

Head:

```
     datetime                time        count
0 2011-01-01 00:00:00      00:00:00       39
1 2011-01-01 01:00:00      01:00:00       40 
2 2011-01-01 02:00:00      02:00:00       10  
3 2011-01-01 03:00:00      03:00:00       14
4 2011-01-01 04:00:00      04:00:00       18
```

Complete stacktrace:

```
File "hello.py", line 43, in <module>
    run()
  File "hello.py", line 41, in run
    ggplot1.draw()    
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ggplot/ggplot.py", line 305, in draw
    callbacks = geom.plot_layer(data, ax)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ggplot/geoms/geom.py", line 115, in plot_layer
    data = self._calculate_stats(data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ggplot/geoms/geom.py", line 275, in _calculate_stats
    new_data = self._stat._calculate(data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ggplot/stats/stat_smooth.py", line 43, in _calculate
    x, y, y1, y2 = smoothers.lowess(x, y, span=span)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ggplot/components/smoothers.py", line 53, in lowess
    result = smlowess(np.array(y), np.array(x), frac=span)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/statsmodels/nonparametric/smoothers_lowess.py", line 128, in lowess
    exog = np.asarray(exog, float)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in ggplot. Can you post the complete plotting code and the head of your data file (`csv_file.head()`). Please also run `<ggplotobject>.draw()` explicitly (`p = ggplot(...) + geom_something(...) + ...; p.draw()`) to get the complete stacktrace if you use ipython. Thanks!

Comment: @JanSchulz I have updated the question with plot and csv head

Comment: Can you also show the complete stacktrace, not only the last line?

Comment: @JanSchulz I have updated the question with complete stack trace

Comment: Thanks! I've added a bug: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/340. currently I'm not sure how to work around...